# How would I stream data into C++ from a CSV to manipulate it later?

Tags: c++, csv

The data in the CSV file is given in an excel workbook, how would I stream this into Replit into a C++ file.

The suggested way of doing this is:

"This can be accessed using a Sensor_Stream class. The constructor of the Sensor_Stream
the class takes a sensorId_t value which specifies the data stream to select. The following is the class constructor method Sensor_Stream(sensorId_tsensor_id).sensorId_t is defined in Sensor_Stream.h"

However, having not coded before I am not sure what this means or how to start, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably that suggestion comes from a source, and that same source defines what `Sensor_Stream.h` is. But we haven't read that book, and it's not a Standard header.

Comment: If you've never coded before you should start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: My advice if you are trying to learn c++ is to get either of the 2 ***Introductory, no previous programming experience*** books from the previous comment and start reading and trying chapter examples at the end of each chapter. At minimum you are several weeks from attempting the task you mentioned in the title.

Comment: Copy the CSV data into your editor.  Prefix the data with `uint32_t data[] = {`.  Append the data with `};`.  I've been doing this for a couple of months now (with font data).